# Getting the color of a specific pixel on the screen using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

I'm writing an extension for a program that helps me automate my streaming. I need to use javascript to get the color value of a specific pixel on my screen and return that value to the program. Whatever method I use also needs to support my multi-monitor setup. I would appreciate any suggestions as I am in over my head a little with this one.

Comment: This article may help: https://thewebdev.info/2022/01/27/how-to-get-pixel-color-from-an-image-with-javascript/

Comment: Massively depends on what your data structure is for the screen, typically monitor colours are displayed as a 2-dimensional array. Therfore to get the pixel at 0,0 you would index the array

`screenPixels[0][0]`

What program are you making an extension for?

Comment: It's a stream deck program called SAMMI